# Python Cannot write unicode string to file

Tags: python, string

I have a string that contains unicode data. 
When I print this string to std out i can see it. When I try to write this string to a file the file for some reason is empty (not always but sometimes). 
My code is the following:

```
print(highways_tweets[n5])
f_n.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,'%s'\n"%(n5,tweet_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),avg,std,z,highway_hit,arr))
f_n.close()
tweets_f=codecs.open("tweets/tweets_%s_%s.csv"%(n5,tweet_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')), "wb", "utf-8")
tweets_f.write('%s'%(highways_tweets[highway]))
tweets_f.close()
```

I can see the variable highways_tweets[highway] printing on the screen but for some reason the file created is empty.

Comment: You are printing `highways_tweets[n5]`but trying to write `highways_tweets[highway]`

Comment: In your code you print two different things (`highway_tweets[n5]` and `highway_tweets[highway]`, otherwise it looks correct, so check you are really printing what you think you do.)

Comment: Oh... Oh Oh..... its August..... And I was trying for different encodings.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common pitfall  when writing singleton tuples : `( a )` is not a tuple but is only `a`, you have to write it `(a,)` to make it a tuple.

So you should write :

```
tweets_f.write('%s'%(highways_tweets[highway],))
```